# how can I run runtime/pprof inside a go program and look at the data inside the same program?

Tags: javascript, go, pprof, heap-profiling

The normal way is to use:

```
go tool pprof
```

But my use case is this: I'm using a golang javascript interpreter like https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto or https://github.com/rogchap/v8go

I want to profile when I run some user supplied javascript to know if it's using too much CPU and I need to kill the go routine.

So a valid case of the javascript taking 30 seconds would be it makes an http connection and is just sitting there idle no cpu use until the connection finally finishes.

So I can't just kill anything that takes too long. I need to only kill javascript that's pegging the cpu or eating up tons of memory.

Comment: https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto/issues/435 not promissing

Comment: There is no simple way to do this. The profiler collects profile data and you would have to analyze this with some 3rd party package.

Comment: If you run the javascript snippet in its own OS process, you can use the linux scheduler features to a) limit CPU time per second and b) get clear insights into consumed CPU time - Design wise that sounds like the better tool for the job. (You can still write your own go wrapper)

Answer (score 2):

As Volker said it's gonna be quite involved to do so in pure go.

Perhaps you could approach the problem differently and use an other mechanism to limit the cpu/memory consumption of the js interpreter ?

You could maybe fork and make the js interpreter run in a different process. That way you could use the standard linux mechanism to control and isolate the resource consumption of a process (cgroups, nice, memory limits, docker etc...)